# error in deploying my application in tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, tomcat

I have my application as .war file and I want to run it in my tomcat server but it is giving me error when I try to start my application after deploy or uploading war file on server. it gives error as:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /jauction could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jauction]]
```

while as other applications are running smoothly.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in your logfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jens, you should look at `logs/catalina.out` to see more details about what's wrong.

You might also want to check `WEB-INF/web.xml` and verify the servlet mapping.